# Converting XmlNode to a String?

Tags: wpf

I referenced a web service in my application, but I am receiving the data as XmlNode, how do I convert this data type to a string?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? You can probably just use the `WebClient` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio just Add Service Reference to WebService url http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx. VS generates proxy class which can use for communication with this WebService. For more information how to add service reference look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx).

Please note that ServiceReference1 is a default namespace name:

```
ServiceReference1.USZipSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.USZipSoapClient();
client.GetInfoByAreaCode("<code goes here>");
```

Comment: -1: that's not the same service URL

Comment: On the page http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=42&CATID=7 there is only description of webservice, but webservice is running on the URL: http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx...

Comment: Thanks. I can't change my vote unless you edit your answer.

Comment: @user3213304: why do you care? Just ignore city and zipcode.

Comment: @user3213304: sorry, I see it's a fairly brain-dead service, and returns all the information as a single string. Try: `string result = client.GetInfoByAreaCode("<code goes here>"); string[] fields = result.Split(' '); string state = fields[1];`

Comment: @user3213304: I'll add an answer once the question reopens (I've voted to reopen now that I know your issue is with a stupid service that returns `XmlNode`), but basically, I recommend you process the data using LINQ to XML.

Comment: @user3213304: `XmlNode result = svc.GetInfoByZIP(_zipCode.Text);
 XElement root = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(result));
 XElement table = root.Element("Table");
 if (table != null)
{
var city = table.Element("CITY");
if (city != null)
{
_result.Text = city.Value;
}
}`